# sails: convert field in sql query to json

Tags: sails.js

I have a query like this:

```
    var sql = "select * from a left join b where a.id in (select field from c)";
    Model.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        return res.json({data:result});
    });
```

which return result something like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "field1": "[\"element 1\", \"element 1\"]",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

you can see that **"[\"element 1\", \"element 1\"]"** is string and i don't like that. i want them to bo json. so the result should something like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "field1": [\"element 1\", \"element 1\"],
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

how can i achieve that?

Comment: someone help me out please

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` on `field1` of each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query represents something like a [many-to-many](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many) relation, you could have a look at the [.populate()](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values) function.

Otherwise you could do it like so:

```js
var data = [{
  "field1": "[\"element 1\", \"element 2\"]",
  "field2": "[\"element 1\", \"element 2\"]",
}];

var parsedData = [];

data.forEach(function(item, index) {
  var parsed = {};

  for (var fieldName in item) {
    try {
      parsed[fieldName] = JSON.parse(item[fieldName]);
    } catch (e) {
      parsed[fieldName] = [];
    }

  }

  parsedData.push(parsed);

});

console.log(parsedData);
```